# Creating string set from given regular expression in language L

Tags: c, regex, automata, fsm, computation

I'm trying to create word sequence in alphabet (given by user) according to regular expression (also given by user) but couldn't make it.

Example scenario 1:

```
Alphabet = [a,b,c]

Regex = (a+c)b*

Word Count = 6

Words = ["a", "c", "ab", "cb", "abb", "cbb"]
```

Example scenario 2:

```
Alphabet = [a,b]

Regex = (a+b)*a

Word Count = 3

Words = ["a", "aa", "ba"]
```

I tried converting regex to postfix / infix then go from there but couldn't build the engine algorithm.

Basically there is 3 operations;

Union (+)
Concat ()
Closure (*)

I wrote one function per operator type;

```
void union(char* x[], char y)
{
    printf("%s\n%c\n", x, y);

    remainingWordCount -= 2;
}

void concat(char* x[], char* y[])
{
    printf("%s%s\n", x, y);
    remainingWordCount--;
}

void closure(char* x[], char* y[])
{
    while (remainingWordCount > 0)
    {
        concat(x, y);
    }
}
```

It's only working in most basic scenarios.

So my question is how can i create set of strings according to given regex without using any regex library? Are there any known algorithms for that?

Comment: Your syntax is a bit confusing (and what you call `Language` is actually the alphabet): `(a+c)` would intuitively be either `ac` or `a(a*)c` but you seem to be using it as `(a|c)`.

Comment: @Arkku thanks for feedback. Changed language to alphabet. Yeah operators are differentiate from standarts i guess.

Comment: Which of the infinite set of strings are you supposed to produce? The `count` shortest ones? The first `count` strings in alphabetic order? Any `count` strings? A uniform random sample of `count` strings? Your first example shows six strings when the request is for five, so it leaves the question open...

Comment: @rici thanks for feedback. That was incorrect. I fixed it. Yeah first *count* strings. (in alphabetic order)

Comment: @Arkku: The use of '+' to denote alternation is actually standard in computer science.

Comment: Also: I presume that the strings need to be unique even if the regular expression provides more than one path which produces the string. For example, a naive scan of  `(a+aa)*` will produce the string of length *k* Fibonacci(*k*+1) times.

Comment: In your first example, the first 5 strings in alphabetic order are `a`, `ab`, `abb`, `abbb`, `abbbb`. (In alphabetic order, you will never produce a string starting with `c`.) That doesn't make the criterion incorrect; it just demonstrates the need for a precise specification.

Comment: @rici that + means something like or (|) in our usage

Comment: @ruakh we take + as a or. So word can start with a or c. Order of a and c should be left then right operand. I should said that way.

Comment: @nuri: i am completely aware of that.

Comment: @ruakh Heh, you are correct, and I must say I'm shocked to discover that I had entirely forgotten that, given that the theory of computation was one of my favourite CS courses at the university. =)

Answer (score 0):

The "brute force" solution is to parse the regular expression into the finite-state machine's state transition graph, with each state having a list of transitions, and each transition having the associated symbol (character) and the next state. You can use a state with no transitions to indicate the terminal state.

Then traverse this graph, remembering the string produced by the transitions. When you reach a terminal state, print the word and decrement the remaining word count, stop when it reaches zero. If it is possible that different paths through the graph end up producing the same word, you also need to remember any words already output and not print/decrement if the same word already exists.

Process the paths in sorted order (such that shorter paths come before longer ones with the same prefix, i.e., as per `strcmp` in C). This avoids getting stuck in a loop, and gives the order you want.

For example, for the regular expression `a*` (pseudocode):

```
state[0] = { {'a', 0}, {'\0', 1} };
state[1] = { }; // terminal state
paths = { { .state = 0, .string = "" } }; // set initial state
```

You start with the only path you have at state `0`, and append to it (separately) both transitions from state `0` to make the new paths:

```
paths = { { .state = 1, .string = "" },
          { .state = 0, .string = "a" } };
```

Since the path with the empty string is ordered first (due to the empty string being sorted before any non-empty string), it is handled first, and since it is in a terminal state with no transitions, it prints the empty string and decrements word count. Then you take the other path and add the transitions from state `0` again, ending up with:

```
paths = { { .state = 1, .string = "a" },
          { .state = 0, .string = "aa" } };
```

etc.

(Disclaimer: This is completely untested, off the top of my head, and there could be corner cases that I didn't think of. Also be aware that the number of paths will explode for non-trivial regular expressions.)

Answer (score 0):

The basic algorithm is simple (if you know how to do all the pieces):

1. [Construct a DFA from the regular expression](https://lambda.uta.edu/cse5317/spring01/notes/node9.html). (Constructing an NFA is not sufficient because the NFA will produce duplicate strings if the regular expression is not deterministic.) The link shows one way of doing this, but there are others; you'll probably find a longer exposition in your formal languages textbook, if you have one.
2. Do an ordered walk (["best-first search"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Best-first_search)) of the (infinite) graph generated from the DFA, where each node is a pair `(state, prefix)` and edges correspond to transitions in the DFA. During the walk, if a node is encountered whose `state` is accepting, produce its `prefix`.

That basic algorithm will work for any ordering relationship between strings with the prefix property: any proper prefix of a string is guaranteed to be less than the string. (If that's not the case, it is possible that there is no "least" element in a set of strings. For example, if the ordering relationship puts a string before any prefix of that string, but is otherwise lexicographic, then any string in `a*` is preceded by the next longer string, which will produce an infinite loop.)

It's important to note that the `state` in the node is only for convenience; it is computationally redundant because it could be regenerated by passing the `prefix` through the DFA. As a consequence, the graph never contains two different nodes with the same `prefix`. The corollary of this observation is that it is not necessary to maintain a set of "seen" nodes, because the successor sets of two distinct nodes are disjoint.

In order to implement the ordered search in step 2, it is necessary to know the *least accepted successor* of each node in the graph, which is not necessarily the immediate successor with the least prefix.

For example, the lexicographic ("alphabetical") ordering relationship is given by:

`(S1, P1) < (S2, P2) iff P1 <lexicographic P2`

In this case, the least accepted successor definitely has the least immediate successor as a prefix, so it is sufficient to order candidates by prefix.

By constrast, with the more common "by length then lexicographic" ordering given by:

`(S1, P1) < (S2, P2) iff |P1| < |P2| or (|P1| = |P2| and P1 <lexicographic P2)`

you cannot predict the order of the least accepted successor of two nodes simply by looking at their immediate successors. You also need to know the minimum number of symbols required to reach an accepting node (or, equivalently, state). Fortunately, that's easy to precompute using any [all-pairs shortest-paths algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem#All-pairs_shortest_paths) on the DFA.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the "iterator" design pattern. I see that you're using C, which is not particularly geared toward object-oriented code, but you can accomplish this by using a structure containing a pointer to a `next` function, a pointer to a `restart` function, and a pointer to a "context" object to be passed to those functions, where the nature of the "context" object will depend on the operator.

In something like `a`, the `next` function returns `"a"` the first time and `NULL` the second time. (The context object keeps track of the `"a"` and whether it's already been returned.)

In something like `...+...`, the `next` can either exhaust the first `...`'s iterator before proceeding to the second, or it can alternate between them, as you prefer. (The context object keeps pointers to the two `...`'s iterators, and which one to call next.)

. . . and so on.

The harderst part is parsing the expression to create all these objects, but it sounds like you're already comfortable with parsing the expression?